# Model evaluation predictions from VertexAI AutoMLTabularTrainingJob

Tags: google-cloud-sdk, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I am following python api documentation to create a AutoMLTabularTrainingJob : https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/automl-api#tabular. It trains successfully with a dataset that consists of train/valid/test splits. I can also get the model evaluation metrics after following this documentation : https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/evaluating-automl-models

However, I am unable to find a way to get the raw predictions that are used to generate the model evaluation metrics. Any pointers would be much appreciated !

Do I have to request for batch predictions again ? https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/predictions/batch-predictions#tabular

Comment: I reviewed the documentation and I haven't found it.... Can you tell little more about the use case. How do you want to use the raw predictions?

Comment: I want to use the predictions to calculate sklearn metrics. e.g. Vertex doesn't provide accuracy.

Comment: fyi https://github.com/googleapis/python-aiplatform/pull/583

Comment: But you need new metrics to be added to Vertex? What do you mean by accuracy. There are other metrics available in Vertex AI...

Comment: Looking at the provided schema, I don't see "accuracy" for instance.

Comment: I meant what is the definition of this "accuracy" metrics? Can you provide some reference?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score.html

Comment: I am not sure it this is available (at least documentation does not mention about this). Auto ML is intended to create and train a model with minimal technical effort. That why it provides predefined [set of metrics](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/training/evaluating-automl-models?hl=en_US#evaluation_metrics_returned_by). Not sure why you cannot use those metrics?